# select the last element in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following mark-up:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.lalala').bind('blur', function (e) {
        CheckFirstInput($(this));
    });
});

<div id="divContainer">
    <input type="text" class="lalala" />
    <p id="img1"></p>
</div>
```

And the following script

```
function CheckFirstInput(element) {
    var txtLength = element.val();
    var parent;
    var lastElement;

    if (txtLength.length < 1) {
        parent = element.parent();
        lastElement = parent.last();
        lastElement.text('prazno e');
    }
    else {
        //element.parent().lastChild().text('4884384f384r34rf');
        parent = element.parent();
        lastElement = parent.last();                
        lastElement.text('ne e prazno');
    }
}
```

If the input field is not empty I want to select the last element of the wrapping div (`<p>`) and change its text. How do I do that?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Приятелю, можеш да елиминираш дублиращия се код като дефинираш `parent` и `lastElement` в началото, вместо да го дефинираш два пъти за двата различни случая :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You needed to select the children() of the element's parent.  You were selecting the last parent. (Which is the parent.)

The following is working.  I also cleaned up the code a bit.

```
$('.lalala').blur( function () {
      CheckFirstInput($(this));
});

function CheckFirstInput(element) {
        if (element.val().length < 1) {
            element.siblings(':last').html('prazno e');
        }
        else {
            element.siblings(':last').html('ne e prazno ');
        }
}
```

### Working Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/CRccw/2/

Comment: Thank you very much! I forgot to select the children of the parent. Silly mistake. Thank you heaps, I'm accepting your answer as the answer to my question in 3 mins. CHeers and thanks again!

Comment: Glad I could help out.  I hate stuff like that.  You can stare at it for hours and then your friend comes over and notices your typo immediately. Heh.

Answer (score 1):

If i got it right you could check `$(element).is(":empty")` and use `parent.siblings(":last-child")`

Comment: :empty is for selecting all elements that have no children (including text nodes). So, your code will always return true since the input has no children.

Comment: Youre right! I confused the input with a textarea whereas `:empty`recognizes text as children too.

Comment: Nice, I didn't know you can use :empty on textareas.

Answer (score 0):

Your question has been answered, but here is another way to do it:

```
$('.lalala').bind('blur', function (e) {
    CheckFirstInput($(this));
});
function CheckFirstInput($el) {
    var $last = $el.siblings().filter(':last');
    var html = ($el.val() == '') ? 'prazno e' : 'ne e prazno';
    $last.html(html);
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/alpacalips/PybWd/1/)